# Flutter: There should be exactly one item existing in [CustomDropdownButton2]

Tags: flutter, dropdownbutton

I always try not to post useless questions in the stack thread and I try to google first but I haven't found a solution yet. so I open a question.

My **Framework** is **Flutter** and I have used the following **library** :

```
dropdown_button2: ^1.9.0
```

### **Problems**

[image]

The problem is that my Custom DropdownButton2 program crashes and as far as I can tell the return value to the list is null, I don't know after the selected item in DropdownButton2, I deleted it make a crash.

so briefly

crashed happens in my app when I delete a selected item on DropdownButton2 and add another item to the hive.

#### My code

```
CustomDropdownButton2(
  value: selectedValue,
  icon: Icon(
    Icons.keyboard_arrow_down,
    color: Colors.white,
  ),
  iconSize: 20,
  hint: context.localeString('message_device_choose'),
  dropdownItems: items,
  buttonDecoration: BoxDecoration(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
    color: Colors.blueAccent,
  ),
  onChanged: (value) {
    setState(() {

      int index = items.indexOf(value.toString());
      final device = box!.getAt(index) as Devices;
      prefManage.setSelectedPhonePref(device.phone);
      selectedPhone = device.phone;

      selectedValue = value.toString();

      prefManage.setSelectedNamePref(value.toString());
    });
  },
),
```

After back add_screen to main_screen list is refreshed

```
void refreshDevices() {
  items.clear();
    for (int i = 0; i < box!.length; i++) {
      final device = box!.getAt(i) as Devices;
      items.add(device.name);
   
    }
  
  setState(() {});
}
```

### Error

[image]

I tried to set the default value to dropdown until fix this problem and I think my problem is the selected value but I can't find the solution to fix it.

I know the problem but I don't know idea to fix it, a problem is when I delete the selected item on CustomDropdownButton2 so finally selectedValue in CustomDropdownButton2 is null and crashes

Comment: Why do you have so many "!" in your code?  Every one of them is a promise that the value will not be null.  Are you *sure* it's not null?

Comment: @RandalSchwartz -  yes, I am sure. so this code is part of my main_screen

Comment: can you include sample data for `items`  that will reproduce the same error

Comment: @Md.YeasinSheikh - yeah but cod is so long just i say my data is true. just i say that i just save names in dropdown button after save in hive.

Comment: you can try `box.toSet().toList()`(shallow copy ig) while creating `items`.

Comment: @Md.YeasinSheikh -  I found the problem but don't know idea to fix it, a problem is when I delete the selected item on CustomDropdownButton2 so finally selectedValue in CustomDropdownButton2  is null and crashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error suggests, the variable `items` is empty. Try to debug whether it goes inside the for loop or not. Because before the for loop, you are clearing the list and if it didn't go inside the loop, the `items` list will be empty which is causing the error.

Comment: Abhishek Doshi - I am sure goes to FOR because it Items loading in with "CustomDropdownButton2" by "refresh Devices" but my problem is here that when I delete a selected device in add_screen and add an item again after back to main_screen crashes happen when deleting the selected item in a  "CustomDropdownButton2";

Comment: - Finally I can fix the problem, My problem is a selected value that is null and reloaded by data in Sharepreference that items no exit item so I get an error. i fixed with manage SharedPreference